# Use Excel VBA to click on a button in Internet Explorer, when the button has no "name" associated

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to use excel to automate the value entering in a time sheet.  The time sheet is on a web page.
Right now I'm able to load the page, enter my username and password and then entering the time sheet by itself.  See code below.

At this point I need to click on a  button to open sub-forms.  I can't know in advance how many sub-forms there will be to open.  I know how to click on a button when it has a "name".  But in this case there's none.    So my updated code below use a loop to open every other subform. It works the first time, but when I do it again

Could someone point me how to determine how many of those button there is in the page and how to click on each?
Following I'm placing the code I have until now and below it, the HTML code of the page I need to interact with.

```
Private Sub time_sheet_filling()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.navigate "http://timesheet.cccc.ca/timesheet/"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

        'Load the logon page
    Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    I = 0
    While I < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(I).Name = "txtUserName" Then
            ' Set text to enter
            objCollection(I).Value = "6666"
        End If
        If objCollection(I).Name = "txtPwd" Then
            ' Set text for password
            objCollection(I).Value = "password"
        End If
        If objCollection(I).Type = "submit" And objCollection(I).Name = "btnSubmit" Then ' submit button clicking
            Set objElement = objCollection(I)
        End If
        I = I + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click    ' click button to load the form

    ' Wait while IE re-loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True  
Dim links, link
Dim n, j
Set links = IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")
n = links.Length  
For j = 0 To n - 1 Step 2
    links(j).Click
'I have some operations to be done will post another question for this
IE.Document.getElementById"DetailToolbar1_lnkBtnSave").Click              'save
IE.Document.getElementById"DetailToolbar1_lnkBtnCancel").Click            'close
Next



End Sub
```

So extract of the html code is below.  I'm trying to click the button that is coded in the last line of the html code below

```
<table width="984" class="Grid" id="dgTime" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="GridHeader">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridItem">
    </tr>
    <tr class="GridItem">
      <td class="GridButtonColumn">
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dgTime$_ctl2$_ctl0','')">
          <img src="images/toolbar/b_edit.gif">
        </a>
      </td
```

Tx Tim for the answers.  Now I'm able to select the first subform button to open it.

```
links(j).click   'j = 0
```

I then save it, close, and come back to the main form.  But then when I try to do

```
links(j).click   'j = 2 this time
```

the second time I get a runtime error 70:  permission denied.  Anymore kind help will be so appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Well that is an anchor, not a button. So select it via tagName

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understant your comment.  How can I find the tagName in the HTML code above?  Is it "dgTime$_ct12$_ct10"  ?  And if so how can I select this one and all the later (ct12$, ct13$ and so on)  if I don't know in advance how much there will be?  Tx.

Comment: Well that is not the tag name I am referring too.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the kind help from Tim Williams, I finally figured out the last détails that were missing.  Here's the final code below.

```
Private Sub Open_multiple_sub_pages_from_main_page()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim buttonCollection As Object
Dim valeur_heure As Object


' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.navigate "http://webpage.com/"

' Wait while IE loading...
While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend


Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "txtUserName" Then
        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "1234"
    End If
    If objCollection(i).Name = "txtPwd" Then
        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "password"
    End If

    If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" And objCollection(i).Name = "btnSubmit" Then ' submit button if found and set
        Set objElement = objCollection(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.Click    ' click button to load page

' Wait while IE re-loading...
While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend

' Show IE
IE.Visible = True
Set Doc = IE.Document

Dim links, link

Dim j As Integer                                                                    'variable to count items
j = 0
Set links = IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")
n = links.Length
While j <= n                                    'loop to go thru all "a" item so it loads next page
    links(j).Click
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    '-------------Do stuff here:  copy field value and paste in excel sheet.  Will post another question for this------------------------
    IE.Document.getElementById("DetailToolbar1_lnkBtnSave").Click              'save
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)                                   'wait
    Loop
    IE.Document.getElementById("DetailToolbar1_lnkBtnCancel").Click            'close
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)                                   'wait
    Loop
    Set links = IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")
    j = j + 2
Wend    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

EDIT: to loop through the collection (items should appear in the same order as they are in the source document)

```
Dim links, link 

Set links = IE.Document.getElementById("dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a")

'For Each loop
For Each link in links
    link.Click
Next link

'For Next loop
Dim n, i
n = links.length
For i = 0 to n-1 Step 2
    links(i).click
Next I
```

Comment: Tx Tim for the answer.  This will have me to be able to click on the first element. So I was thinking on using the following to open all the items.  Set buttonCollection = IE.Document.getelementbyid"dgTime").getElementsByTagName("a") '(0)
    j = 1 'buttonCollection.Length
    
    While j <= buttonCollection.Length

Comment: Tx again Tim,  I guess I could have mention that I need to select every other element, first, third, fifth and so on.  How can I skip one if I use the "for each" method?  My last question wasn't precise enough and I apologize.  Thank you for the generosity of your time and knowledge.

Comment: I'm keep looking to find my solution with the "link.click" method.   So to be sure I don't bother again on the same matter, how could I select let's say the 9th item of the "link"  in the "links"  in the answer above

Answer (score 3):

**CSS selector:**

Use a CSS selector of `img[src='images/toolbar/b_edit.gif']`

This says select element(s) with `img` tag with attribute `src` having value of `'images/toolbar/b_edit.gif'`

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You can apply the selector with the `.querySelector` method of `document`.

```
IE.document.querySelector("img[src='images/toolbar/b_edit.gif']").Click
```