# Is there a way to click on a radio button when Excel VBA says its not visible but it is actually visible?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, usps

How do I click on a radio button on the webpage in a form? I am trying to write a code to automate form filling with Excel VBA.
Here is the problem statement: Need to click on one of the three options on the page "[https://moverguide.usps.com/mgo/disclaime](https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo/disclaimer)r" or [https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo-m/disclaimer](https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo/disclaimer) namely "Individual", "Family" and "Business", I get the following error:

> Run time error 11: NoSuchElementErrorElement Cannot click on element

when I use this sample code:

```
If var = individual or family or business Then
        If obj.FindElementById("move-type-var").IsPresent Then
            obj.FindElementById("move-type-var").Click
        End If
```

or this error:

> Runtime error 7
>
> NoSuchElementError

when I run the following sample code:

```
if condition satisfied then
                obj.FindElementByCss ("css=.row--reskin:nth-child(1) .reskin__card:nth-child(1) > .reskin__card--label)")

            End If
```

I obtained the css parameter by extracting the css target from Firefox. Basically, I recorded a script using Selenium IDE to see what exactly is happening so that I leverage appropriate target value for my Excel VBA solution.

One of the properties in the IE console (F12) when I manually check the source code is "aria-checked" set to checked/true. This happens when I click on one of the options myself. Is that what I have to enable in the code?

Just a disclaimer: Good with Excel VBA overall but exploring webforms and quite new to this aspect.

Tools: Selenium webdriver for IE11, MS Excel (office 365), VBA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153744/use-excel-vba-to-click-on-a-button-in-internet-explorer-when-the-button-has-no

Comment: Thanks, Mech. Let me see if I can do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are labels not radio buttons. You can target with css attribute = value selectors; where you concatenate the option string of interest into the `for` attribute value. I use a slightly different start url to avoid unnecessary steps.

```
Dim var As String

'individual, family, business
var = "business"

obj.findElementByCss("[for='move-type-" & var & "']").Click
```

Comment: That was going to be my other attempt - try using label name in the css. I do see in the source code that these are of the type radio:{<input data-v-2b1acfa4="" tabindex="0" role="radio" type="radio" name="moveTypeRadios" value="INDIVIDUAL" class="radio-cards__input">}

Comment: And just curious, which start URL did you use? It usually always goes to "...mgo/disclaimer" or "...mgo-m/disclaimer" on my end. The other link is using the header which is likely for tracking such as "...mgo/disclaimer?referral=MG80"

Comment: I  looked at https://moversguide.usps.com/mgo-m/move-combined  as start url. I forgot to include that (Sorry). For the radion html you show - yes, you could have tried [type=radio][value=" & val & "]" - I didn't see that as the expected interactable part of the page which are the label elements.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have used this URL and it's simpler to interact with (haven't seen a reCaptcha on this page so far). There's another issue that I am running into on this page. When it comes to selecting the date fields, the desktop ('...mgo/disclaimer") version can have the date sent directly to the input box using sendkeys. Any guidance you can provide on how to accomplish this on the mobile version (",,,mgo-m/move-combined')? In the meantime, I am going to fiddle and research how to click on the date with such pop-up calendar buttons on the mgo-m page

Comment: You could stick with your current initial url and still use the same idea for clicking the labels. Then you can carry on with your sendkeys for date fields. I will have a look at the appropriate method using the start url I gave in comments. It sounds like it is the more fiddly spinner up/down clicking type where you click an up/down until target value achieved.

Comment: I literally went through many of your feedbacks on other questions to find a solution. Nothing from the solutions out there seem to work on this (mgo-m) page properly to set the right date. Were you to be look into it? I am more inclined to using the mgo-m page as it does not really give me the captcha so would prefer to find a solution that works on this page. If you weren't able to that's okay too. Thought will give a shout.